# this.refs.something.value return undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Click edit and then there will be an input bar appears, I expect when I click the save button, I can get the user's input but why I got undefined? There's no error in the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/2onzybk6/2

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items : [1, 2, 3],
      isEdit: null
    };
  },
  renderEditForm() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="newItem" />
        <button onClick={ this.saveHandler }>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  ItemCtrl(index) {
    if (index != this.state.isEdit) {
      return (
        <div className="itemCtrlWrap">
          <button onClick={ this.editHandler.bind(this, index) }>Edit</button>
        </div>
       );
    }
  },
  editHandler(i) {
    this.setState({ isEdit: i });
  },
  saveHandler() {

    console.log(this.refs.newItem.value); // why is this undefined?
    this.setState({ isEdit: null });
  },

  renderItem() {
    return (
     this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
       <li key={ i }> {this.state.isEdit == i ? this.renderEditForm() : item} {this.ItemCtrl(i)}</li>)
    );
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of React you are using requires you to do this:

`this.refs.newItem.getDOMNode().value`

In more recent versions when you do `this.refs.newItem` it would actually return the dom node but in the version you are using in this fiddle it returns a React component object. When you call `getDOMNode()` it will get the actual DOM element and then you can call regular DOM properties

Comment: nice catch buddy thank you. One question, why is the input field's value gone when I change state? I did not alter that part, react does that for me?

Comment: Regarding editing questions, indentation changes are welcome but please avoid changing the code, even if it's best practices.

Comment: That would have been an accident @EmileBergeron I pasted into text editor to change indention there, still haven't found good way to do within stack overflow when it was originally indented incorrectly.

Comment: It's all good, wasn't a big change anyway! Thanks for your edit ;)

Comment: @Sandy in your <input> you do not have a `value=`  property on it. If you wanted it to maintain any sort of state you would do something like `<input type="text" ref="newItem" value={this.state.inputValue} />` and then make sure there is an actual state or prop that is controlling the input value.